# Can Activity Monitor monitor activities started from external applications?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, activity-monitor

I know Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor can monitor activities started in the current application. I'm wondering if it can monitor to see if an activity from a separate app gets started.

I have an app where if you click a button, it launches the MainActivity of a separate app. Could you configure the activity monitor to detect that?

Comment: This sort of integration testing is what UI Automator is for.